# Magento2 How To Read Data From Excel File

Tags: magento2, file, excel

I want to read data from excel file (Not from .csv file but from excel file) .

Does anyone know how can i get data from excel file ?

Answer (score 5):

Please try this way may it work .

> include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
>    File Get from this [link](https://github.com/affinitybridge/phpexcel/blob/master/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php)

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($location);
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $total_rows = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $total_columns = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    $set_excel_query_all=array();
    for($row =2; $row <= $total_rows; $row++) {
        $singlerow = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $total_columns . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
        $single_row=$singlerow[0];
        $set_excel_query['store_id']=$single_row[0];
        $set_excel_query['employee_uid']=$single_row[1];
        $set_excel_query['opus_id']=$single_row[2];
        $set_excel_query['item_description']=$single_row[3];
        if($single_row[4])
        {
            $set_excel_query['opus_transaction_date']= date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($single_row[4]));
        }
        $set_excel_query['opus_transaction_num']=$single_row[5];
        $set_excel_query['opus_invoice_num']=$single_row[6];
        $set_excel_query['customer_name']=$single_row[7];
        $set_excel_query['mobile_num']=$single_row[8];
        $set_excel_query['opus_amount']=$single_row[9];
        $set_excel_query['rq4_amount']=$single_row[10];
        $set_excel_query['difference']=$single_row[11];
        $set_excel_query['ocomment']=$single_row[12];
        $set_excel_query['mark_delete']=$single_row[13];
        if($single_row[14])
        {
            $set_excel_query['upload_date']= date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($single_row[14]));
        }
        $set_excel_query_all[]=$set_excel_query;
    }

   print_r($set_excel_query_all);
```

Comment: Thanks @Chirag For Answer it is good , but is there any way from magento 2 core without using external library?

Comment: @SanjayShiyal did you find any solution using Magento2 ?